# How to get rid of MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, culture

I've spent almost 8 hours by searching for an answer on how to get rid of that freakin' exception. I have an C# application which needs to be localized to several languages. I'm using parent-level language names for resource files i.e. for english language, my resX file is `lang.en.resx`, for czech it is `lang.cs.resx`. So I'm no bothering about language variants like en-US, en-GB.
Default namespace for my app is GSMMaster, my app is GSMMaster. My resource manager is constructed like this :

```
if (!_autoDetectLanguage) 
    _currentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(_selectedLanguage);
else
    _currentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

_rManager = new ResourceManager("GSMMaster.lang", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I have two resX files : czech, and english. Czech works just fine, but english throws that exception.
I've tried all options which I've found with no luck so far. Does anybody have some experience with that behavior ? One language resource works and second not ? Or, is there some conventional approach on how to create those files ?

Thanks a lot.